# How do first integrals help you solve differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

I am reading about Euler-Lagrange equations and this particular section is a little unclear. Consider the differential equation

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x}\\
\dot{y}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
-7x^{\frac{6}{7}}y^{\frac{1}{7}}\\
7x^{\frac{1}{7}}y^{\frac{6}{7}}
\end{bmatrix}\quad (x(0),y(0)) = (x_{0},y_{0}), \quad x_{0},y_{0} \neq 0.$$

How do I solve this using the fact that $H(x,y) = x^{\frac{2}{7}} + y^{\frac{2}{7}}$ is a first integral of the above differential equation?

If we let $u = (x,y)$, $u(0) = (x_{0},y_{0})$ be a solution to the above differential equation, then $H(u)$ is a constant. In particular, $H(u) = H(u(0))$ for all $t$ since a first integral is constant along the solutions of the differential equation.

After this, I am a confused. I know that the level sets of $H(x,y)$ looks like an asteroid. But how does this help me? Is each level set of $H$ the orbit of a solution to the differential equation? How do I know that there aren't any extraneous points in the level set that are not part of $u$?

If the above is correct, I don't understand how to write down the general solution from this level curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The level sets of a first integral are not necessarily orbits, but the orbits are pieces of these level sets.  If $L$ is a level set and $E$ the set of equilibrium points,  the connected components of $L \backslash E$ should be orbits.

EDIT: If you can parametrize a level set (say as $x = X(s), y=Y(s)$), then substituting $x = X(s(t)), y = Y(s(t))$ in to the differential equation should give you a single first-order differential equation for $s(t)$.  In your example 
I would try $x = c\; \cos(s)^7$, $y = c\;\sin(s)^7$.

Comment: Thank you. Could you define what an equilibrium point is? Is that the same as a rest point?

Comment: Yes, it is.  A point $(x_0,y_0)$ that is a constant solution.

Comment: I thought from here the problem would be obvious, but after solving for $s(t) = t + C_{1}$, then writing $x(s(0)) = x_{0}$ and $y(s(0)) = y_{0}$ doesn't seem to let me find a constant to match the initial conditions.

I seem end up with a solution that says, $u = (x,y)$, $x = H(x_{0},y_{0})\cos^{7}(t+C_{1})$ and $y= H(x_{0},y_{0}) \sin^{7}(t+C_{1})$, but there doesn't seem to be a way to find the constant $C_{1}$.

Comment: Unless the only initial conditions where a solution exists are when $x_{0} = 0, y_{0}\neq 0, C_{1} = \pi/2 + 2k\pi$, or $x_{0}\neq 0, y_{0} = 0, C_{1} = 2k\pi$, but that seems surprising to me.

Comment: Note that with $x = c \cos(s)^7$ and $y = c \sin(s)^7$ we have $H(x,y) = c^{2/7} (\cos^2(s) + \sin^2(s)) = c^{2/7}$.
Given $(x_0,y_0)$ with $x_0 > 0$ and $y_0 > 0$, we take $c = H(x_0,y_0)^{7/2}$, and then we want $\tan(s_0) = \sin(s_0)/\cos(s_0) = (y_0/x_0)^{1/7}$.

Comment: Thank you, it took me a while to go through the details, but I see where I went wrong now.